# Passing arrays in JSON to javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I did a search on stackoverflow and did not find the exact thing that I am looking for.

I am using an in-house server side language, like PHP. I have two drop downs A and B on a web page. B gets populated with values from database based on the input from A. Simple problem right? So I fire an onchange even on A and call a javascript function, which does a post Ajax call to the server side code. This server side code should do the query and return the results to a responseHandler which should give the results as post data to B. The problem I am having is in the server side code, when I do the query I get a bunch of rows as array. How do I pass that array to the Javascript responseHandler ? I am trying to send is JSON but not with much success. Below is the server side code:

```
// If - then - else , !, query, and get are functions in the language
{if {! {query output post get_data_qry_str}}{then
    //JSON object
   {
      "status":"error",
      "errorMessage":"Query did not succeed"
   }
}{else
   //JSON Object
   {
      "status":"success",
      "successMessage":"how do I pass output here ?"
   }
}}

output.values={1,2,3}
```

If I say {get output} it passes "", if I say {get output.values} it passes 1.
Let me know if I should post more clarity on the syntax of the server side language.

Comment: `output.values = [1,2,3];` is the correct way to instantiate a new `array`. `{}` is the `object` literal syntax.

Comment: Are you using jquery/mootools, or rolling your own ajax handler? Both of those libraries will handle json->javascript conversions for you automatically.

Comment: Yes, please clarify the syntax. It is confusing because I can't tell whether some `{}` are part of a JSON representation of an Object, or if they are blocks in your server side code.

Comment: Am I correct in my understanding that your problem is converting your server side object(presumably a query result of some sort) into a JSON array? If your are using an in-house server side language then chances are there are no 3rd party libraries available for serializing your server object into JSON. You'll probably have to write it yourself.

Comment: @Marc B Yes I am using my own Javascript Handler and not any libraries

Comment: @Hyangelo - I think you are right, I will have to write my own JSON serialize function, but is there a way I can use some javascript for that? May be I am not making sense?

Comment: Can you execute javascript in your server side language? Is it an entire language or just a scripting language that is perhaps running on top of something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading @Hyangelo comments, I wrote my own serializing function. I thought I will put it here just in case someone else wants to see it. Below is the JSON for the success part

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "successMessage":"[
       // for, length, get, set are functions here
       {for x=0 to {length output} do
          {get comma}
          "{get output.values[x]}"
          {set comma ,}
       }
    ]"
}
```

I also learned, that in Javascript, to send arrays as post_data to a post Ajax call, you can do this,

```
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; ++i)
{
   post_string += '&values=' + arr[i];
}

instead of 

post_string = '&values=' + arr;
```

It might be trivial, but I am new to JS and took me a while to figure.. Thanks @Hyangelo
Sorry could not post a reply untill 8 hrs..

Comment: Sure, no problem. I'm curious though, why are you using an in-house server side?

Comment: Legacy code.. besides its an interpreted language and very light weight.. perfect for the type of application we are building

Comment: Figured as much. The example you posted above will work(except when output.values have quotes in it, for that you need to encode/escape it) but if you are planning to use JSON responses elsewhere I would suggest building a real serializer to reuse. By real serializer I mean something that is capable of turning a server side object into a valid JSON string. For example, look at flexjson or gson(java json serializers)

Comment: @Hyangelo Great point.. I should get into the habit of always encoding the post_data.. Thanks for the tips on the serializer.. I will try to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP: **http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php**